# moment.js date to timestamp internationalization (german)

Tags: javascript, internationalization, timestamp, momentjs

I could not find a similar question so here it goes:
Moment.js does not seem to understand months in other language than english when doing the formmating.

Moment.js with locales is in the assets and when I try following:

```
moment('1. März 2014').format('LLLL');
"Invalid date"
```

on the other hand this works:

```
moment('1. March 2014').format('LLLL');
"Samstag, 1. März 2014 00:00 Uhr"
```

I already have some workarounds but it would be awesome to make it clean. Any ideas what an U diubg wrong?

I use chrome 38.0.2125.111 and moment.js 2.8.3.

Please tell me if you need more info about the problem.

EDIT

It looks like only some months are problematic. This works perfectly:

```
moment('1. Januar 2014').format('LLLL');
"Mittwoch, 1. Januar 2014 00:00
```

I thought it might be special chars like ä in März. But this won't work neither:

```
moment('1. Dezember 2014').format('LLLL');
"Invalid date"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the locale to german explicitly and provide the format of the input

```
moment.locale("de"); moment('1. März 2014', "DD. MMMM YYYY").format("LLLL"));
```

Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/sbbg3dzt/

Comment: Just found out it is necessary to provide the format string like in your example. Without it will not work even with the locale command.